# Subsequential limit and interval

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ of real numbers is such that $a_{n+1}− a_n \to 0$. Prove that the set of limits of its convergent subsequences is the interval with endpoints $\liminf_{n \to \infty} a_n$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty}a_n$.

Can this be done this way that since the elements of the sequence are dense hence if you take a point then there are infinitely many elements around its neighbourhood and hence it acts as a subsequential limit now between lim sup and lim inf every point is a subsequential limit hence the proof follows
Please help whether the above method is right or wrong

Comment: It is well-known that for any sequence the lim inf is its minimal subsequential limit, and lim sup its maximal one. The extra condition should then garantuee that all intermediate values also appear as such subsequential limits.

Comment: The elements of the sequence are dense? not for $\frac{1}{n}$ e.g.

Comment: How will I prove this fact that all intermediate value also appear

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think dense means "dense in $[\liminf a_n, \limsup a_n].$"

Comment: @zhw That's what's to be shown, not assumed.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  Just pointing out that $1/n$ is not a counterexample to "dense".

Comment: @zhw. There not dense in $[0,0]$...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, you're right, I see now. Thanks